# Responsive with arbitrary number by user, not automatically in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it feasible to developers specify when the contents of the web page stack by responsive design? So for example if you are in 1200 x 1800 resolution, you are in the following display:

```
[A] [B]
```

However, if you are in 1000 x 1800 resolution, your display automatically in the following stack format by the virtue of Twitter Bootstrap's responsive functionality (I use Bootstrap 3):

```
[A]
[B]
```

However, is it feasible for developers specify when the responsiveness occurs - for example, when the resolution is less than 1100 x 1800, the above stack occurs - and if it's feasible, how can I specify it?

I use Bootstrap, HTML5, CSS3 as well as node.js, but I think node is irrelevant in this case.

I use Google Chrome, and don't care about how the other browsers react to the change.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "resolution", you mean browser window size, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant the browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to have a look at [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) ([2](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)), e.g. quoting from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Actually, I've used it and thought that it's exactly the one I should use, but it didn't change at all with and without the media query... Or maybe, the link element has to take in `media` attribute? I took the link element approach without `media` attribute, and in the linked file I wrote every style setting as well as media query on any devices... is it not a valid way to use media query?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

I hope help you